# Show one div and hide rest all

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, css

Now am using fade in fadeout to toggle the content on button click.

the script i used for the same is

```
function showHide(divId){
    if (document.getElementById(divID).style.display == "none") {
        $('#'+divID).fadeIn(3000);

    } else {
        $('#'+divID).fadeOut(3000);
    }
}
```

how to modify the above code to show content on button click.

consider i have 2 buttons

```
<button> button1</button>
<button> button2</button>


<div id="div1"> content of button 1 </div>
<div id="div2" style="display:hidden"> content of button 2</div>
```

i wanna show either of the div, when button1 is clicked, button 2 content shouldn't be visible and vice verse.

Answer (score 1):

Update `showHide`

```
function showHide(divID) {
    $("div").not("#" + divID).fadeOut(3000);
```

Choosing to fade them out every time is fine since hiding a div would not show another.  You should probably also give all of these divs a class and use that instead of just `"div"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` event on button.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this);">button1</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this);">button2</button>
<div id="div1"> content of button 1 </div>
<div id="div2" style="display:hidden"> content of button 2</div>
```

In the script tag, this function can be used.

```
function ShowHide(element)
{
   if ($(element).attr("id") == "button1")
   {
      $("#div1").fadeIn(3000);
      $("#div2").fadeOut(3000);
   }
   else if ($(element).attr("id") == "button2")
   {
      $("#div2").fadeIn(3000);
      $("#div1").fadeOut(3000);
   }
}
```

If you want to hide all the divs except one, you can use code similar to the following:

```
$("div").fadeOut(3000);
```

This will hide all the divs.

Then this will show the proper div:

```
$("#divId").fadeIn(3000);
```

Use proper Id of div in divId

Comment: no it's not working see the link for details http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/utaxK/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner at js, but try this:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn1"> button1</button>
<button id="btn2"> button2</button>

<div id="div1"> content of button 1 </div>
<div id="div2" class="hidden"> content of button 2</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none;}
```

JS:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
   $('#div2').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div1').removeClass('hidden');
})
$('#btn2').click(function(){
   $('#div1').addClass('hidden');
   $('#div2').removeClass('hidden');
})
```

Here's a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G69EJ/3/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your HTML into this :

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this);"> button1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this);"> button</button>


<div id="div1" class='divShowHide'> content of button 1 </div>
<div id="div2" class='divShowHide'> content of button 2</div>
```

now  try this code :

```
 firstCall this function on domready:

 $(document).on('click',function(){
      $('.divShowHide').fadeOut(30);
 });

function ShowHideDiv(divId){

   $('.divShowHide').fadeOut(3000);
   $(divId).fadeIn(3000);

 }
```